# How to change the background color of selected expandable table view cell

Tags: ios, swift

I need to change the background color in expandable table view cell, when it is selected. What I have done is, I placed three UIViews in a cell. When the first view in the cell is selected, the remaining two views will be expanded. It is working. Now I need to change the color of the first view alone when a cell is selected. Used the following code, it changes the color of third view in the cell. But I want the first view to change and stay in orange color until the other cell is selected. Could anyone help ?

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class NewTableViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate{

    let viewObj = CustomCellTableViewCell()
    let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
     var selectedIndex = -1

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return totalCustomer().0
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->CGFloat
     {
        if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
            return 160;
        }
        else {
            return 40;
        }
     }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{
            print("entered")
            let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! CustomCellTableViewCell
            let row = indexPath.row
            var nameArray = [String]()
            nameArray = totalCustomer().1
            cell.firstViewLabel.text = nameArray[row]
            var emailArray = [String]()
            emailArray = totalCustomer().2
            cell.secondViewLabel.text = emailArray[row]

            return cell
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
         cell?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
         cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
      }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
      {             
          if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
              selectedIndex = -1
          } else {
              selectedIndex = indexPath.row
          }
          self.tableView.beginUpdates()
          self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
          self.tableView.endUpdates()
       }

       func totalCustomer()->(Int,[String],[String])
       {
          let request: NSFetchRequest<Customers> = Customers.fetchRequest()
          var customerList = [String]()
          var customerEmailList = [String]()
          var customerCount = 0
          do {
             let results = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request as! NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>)
             print(results.count)
             if  results.count > 0
             {
                for _ in 0..<results.count
                {
                   let match = results[customerCount] as! NSManagedObject
                   print(match.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
                   customerList.append(match.value(forKey: "name") as! String)
                   customerEmailList.append(match.value(forKey: "email") as! String)
                   customerCount = customerCount + 1
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                    //statusLabel.isHidden = false
             }

          }
          catch let error
          {
              print("Label\(error.localizedDescription)")
          }
          print(customerCount)
          return (customerCount,customerList,customerEmailList)
      }


}

import UIKit
class CustomCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondViewLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdViewLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var secondHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        secondView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        secondView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        thirdView.layer.borderWidth = 0.1
        thirdView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    }
    var showsDetails = false {
        didSet {
            secondHeightConstraint.priority = showsDetails ? 250 : 999
            thirdHeightConstraint.priority = showsDetails ? 250 : 999

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you are storing your selected `IndexPath.row` in  `selectedIndex` and your `firstView` is public and you are reloading your `UITableView` after selecting a cell, the following additional code in `cellForRowAt` method should be enough.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{

   if self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
      cell.firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow // selected color
   }else {
      cell.firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // default color
   }    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{     
      var indexPathArray: [IndexPath] = []
      if selectedIndex != -1 {
         indexPathArray.append(IndexPath(row: selectedIndex, section: 0)) // previous selected row
      }        
      if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
          selectedIndex = -1
      } else {
          selectedIndex = indexPath.row
          indexPathArray.append(indexPath) // currently selected row
      }
      self.tableView.beginUpdates()
      if indexPathArray.count > 0 {
         self.tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPathArray, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
      }
      self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: The color is changing correctly when we select a cell. but, when we click the other cell, the previous selected cell remains with the same orange color. To turn it back to normal color(blue), we need to select the same cell again.

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk, I apologise. I thought you were calling `self.tableView.reloadData()`. Please check my edited answer and let me know if it resolves the problem

Comment: I see you are storing currently selected index path to the indexPathArray (indexPathArray.append(indexPath)' and reloading it. I wonder how does the previously selected index is going back to normal color ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk, Value of `selectedIndex` is changed. Inside `cellForRowAt` method, we added logic for color. We are reloading both previously selected and currently selected indexPaths. Earlier we are only loading currently selected indexPath

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you KrishnaCA!

Answer (score 1):

Move the colour changing login to cellForRowAt method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) ->UITableViewCell{

   if self.selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
      cell.firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange  // Highlight color
   }else {
      cell.firstView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue // Original color
   }    
}
```

Remember to update the previous row also to remove the background color:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
      {   
           previousIndex = selectedIndex          
          if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
              selectedIndex = -1
          } else {
              selectedIndex = indexPath.row
          }
          var myPrevIP = IndexPath(row: previousIndex, section: indexPath.section)
          var indexPathArray: [Any] = [myPrevIP, indexPath]
          self.tableView.beginUpdates()
          self.tableView.reloadRows(at:indexPathArray,with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
          self.tableView.endUpdates()
       }
```

Comment: Can you please edit NSIndexPath and NSArray lines to swift 3 . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`UITableView` already has the selection mechanism implemented.

In your cell, you can control your background color:

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBInspectable var normalColor: UIColor = UIColor.white
    @IBInspectable var highlightedColor: UIColor = UIColor.red
    @IBInspectable var selectedColor: UIColor = UIColor.blue

    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
        refreshBackground()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        refreshBackground()
    }

    func refreshBackground() {
        if isHighlighted {
            backgroundColor = highlightedColor
        }
        else if isSelected {
            backgroundColor = selectedColor
        }
        else {
            backgroundColor = normalColor
        }
    }
}
```

And using `@IBInspectable` in the cell let's you configure the colors directly in storyboard.